# Close a batch file after running the jar file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jar

I wrote a batch file that runs a jar file. But after it runs the jar file the batch file doesn't close until the jar file is also closed. How can I close the command screen when it opens the jar file?( when the jar file is open I want to close the command screen.)

My batch file :

```
@echo off
java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar ".\sample.jar"
exit
```

Comment: It's interesting that "java" and "javaw" performing diffrent result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) before the rest of the command.

Comment: my batch file @echo off
java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar ".\sample.jar"
exit

Comment: ----> `start java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar ".\sample.jar"`

Comment: when I use start I am getting "windows cannot find '-jar'. Make sure you type the name correctly..."

Answer (score 12):

I have recently had this problem and for someone other in future, complete and simple way is here:

```
@echo off
start javaw -jar "nameOfJar.jar"
exit
```

This starts jar and close CLI.

Important is the "start" command and the "javaw" command for windows environment.

Comment: Important is "start" and "javaw" not "javac".

Comment: worked with me using start javaw and exit at the end.