# How do I run a .bat file without a terminal (remaining open)?

Tags: jar, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a jar file with a .bat (the jar file doesn't seem to want to open on its own but thats a different issue for now) but as the java file runs for a long time, the command prompt remains open (while the .bat/.jar is still running)

I do not want this.

I read somewhere that you can use a .cmd file and the command(s):

```
cmd /c bat.bat
exit
```

To run a bat file without a command prompt. But that isn't working for me. When I click the .cmd program it just opens a command promopt and keeps printing "cmd /c bat.bat exit" over and over in a loop.

What am I doing wrong, was my .cmd command wrong? Is there another way to run a .bat without a command prompt remaining open?

Thanks alot.

Comment: I tried to retag your question to put `batch-file` in front, but it seems like StackOverflow wants to keep it in this order. Dunno.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window):

> Save the following as wscript, for instance, hidecmd.vbs after
>   replacing "testing.bat" with your batch file's name.
>
> ```
> Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
> Dim strArgs
> strArgs = "cmd /c testing.bat"
> oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
> ```
>
> The reference is here
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx

Comment: I found this question to have a better answer. use the start command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314638/close-a-batch-file-after-running-the-jar-file

Comment: Using the start command will still flash the terminal window briefly, whereas this option runs the script completely off screen and silently